# Add new announcement link viewable by permissions

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I created a Content query web part on my home page which is from an announcement list from a sub site. I wanted to add the "Add new Announcement" link below it, but only viewable to those who have access to do so in the actual list.

Is this at all possible?

I am using SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Answer (score -1):

The "Add new Announcement" link on the Announcements web part will only show up for people that have "Write" permissions for the site anyway. For example: I have full control along with 2 others, everyone else that uses the site has Read/View Only permissions so cannot update the web part. So if you "Copy Shortcut" on the "Add an announcement" link and then paste it elsewhere it should retain the permissions i would imagine.

Comment: I want the text to be visible to only those users that have access. Just like any other Add Announcement link text.

Comment: https://blog.imason.com/4-ways-to-target-content-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Everytime I try to edit the page with SharePoint Designer it reverts itself.